# iOS10 Large Search Bar

Tags: xcode, search, uisearchbar, xcode8, ios10

How can you achieve this search bar style in Xcode 8?

For instance this style is being used in iOS10 Music and Maps app.

[image: Large Search Bar]

Comment: Apple's inconsistent UI elements being a private API? Shocking! Before you start implementing on your own, make sure to open an enhancement request with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com .

Comment: It seems the custom search bar is not opening in a navigation bar, so that removes one obstacle. Instead, there is a content view that includes it and the segment bar. It transitions to this content view when the bar becomes first responder.